# plotly express for large data sets

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame()
dfa["travel_time(min)"] = range(100000)
fig = px.ecdf(dfa["travel_time(min)"], x="travel_time(min)")
#fig.write_html("debug.html")
fig.show()
```

The 100k points are producing a graphic, which is lagging (with 10k points it is working fine).
How can I fix this? Is it possible to somehow precalculate the graphic?

Comment: my current solution is to cheat and use dfa["travel_time(min)"].sample(n=10000, random_state=0) and hope that it doesn't change too much :D

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** Using Plotly express's ecdf or hist functions with large datasets is not advised because it encapsulates **all** data points in the chart instead of precalculating the bins. Use Matplotlib to display pre-calculated bins or display a sample of your data. Because of the law of large numbers, if you randomly sample a large portion of your data this will not affect statistics of the output distribution.

Using Plotly express's ecdf or hist functions with large datasets, such as the 100,000 data points in your example, is suboptimal. The main issue stems from the fact that these functions directly incorporate every single data point into the graph. When dealing with such a large dataset, it can lead to lagging and performance issues.

Here's why: Plotly's ecdf (Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function) plots every point in the data range, making it increasingly resource-intensive with larger datasets. When you go from 10k to 100k points, the browser or rendering engine must handle a ten-fold increase in information, which can cause noticeable lag.

To fix this, you may consider using other libraries or methods that enable binning or down-sampling the data before visualization. Here's an example using matplotlib and numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming 'dfa' is your DataFrame
x = dfa["travel_time(min)"]
ecdf_x, ecdf_y = np.sort(x), np.arange(1, len(x) + 1) / len(x)

plt.plot(ecdf_x, ecdf_y)
plt.xlabel('travel_time(min)')
plt.ylabel('ECDF')
plt.show()
```

This code still plots the ECDF, but by using matplotlib and numpy, it might handle larger datasets more efficiently. Adjusting the binning or sampling rate can further improve performance if necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).